# Proguard Interface class which has another interface inside

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Interface class A and in the Class A i have another Interface B 
I am trying to proguard the Package and  when i build it in gradle I getting

The below error

```
symbol:   class B
  location: interface A
../Progaurd/android/trunk/sample/module-c/src/main/java/com/c/db/C.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
public class C implements B
```

The actual class is as follows

```
public interface A{
       public interface B{
         ...
       }
}
```

I have tried with the below lines in proguard-project.txt file

```
-keep class * implements com.sample.manager.storage.A.B
```

Please help me....

Answer (score 0):

```
-keep public interface com.sample.manager.storage.A$B {*;}
```